# Setting Placeholder in OpenAPI specfication info.version

Tags: maven, openapi, maven-plugin, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

is it somehow possible to define the `info.version` attribute in openapi.yaml as a placeholder and to replace this placeholder with each maven build by the maven artifact version?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven replacer plugin might be one solution. For me it's working well.

**openapi.yaml**

```
...
info:
  version: OPENAPI_VERSION_REPLACER # version of this interface specification is set during build
...
```

**Maven profiles/profile/build/plugins/**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <version>${maven-replacer-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>api-spec-path-replacement</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <basedir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/openapi</basedir>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.yaml</include>
        </includes>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>version:.*OPENAPI_VERSION_REPLACER.*#</token>
                <value>version: ${project.version} # Automatically set by maven replacer plugin -
                </value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```